# equivalent projections in finite factors are unitarily equivalent

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Why are two Murray von Neuman equivalent projections $p$ and $q$ in a finite factor unitarily equivalent?

Comment: This is Exercise 6.1.9 in these notes by Vaughn Jones on Von Neuman Algebras https://math.vanderbilt.edu/jonesvf/VONNEUMANNALGEBRAS2015/VonNeumann2015.pdf

Answer (score 2):

In a finite factor, you have that $p,q$ are equivalent if and only if $\tau(p)=\tau(q)$. So $p\sim q$ if and only $1-p\sim 1-q$. If $v$ is partial isometry with $v^*v=p$, $vv^*=q$, and $w$ is a partial isometry with $w^*w=1-p$, $ww^*=1-q$, then $u=v+w$ is a unitary with $upu^*=q$.

Comment: But how to check $u^*u=1$?

Comment: That's completely standard. 
\begin{align}
u^*u&=(v^*+w^*)(v+w)=v^*v+w^*w+v^*w+w^*v \\
&=p+1-p+v^*q(1-q)w+w^*(1-q)qv\\
&=1.
\end{align}
This is enough, since the context is a finite factor. It should be intuitively obvious: $v$ maps $pH$ onto $qH$ isometrically, and $w$ maps $(1-p)H$ onto $(1-q)H$, so their sum is a surjective isometry.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I saw a similar conclusion : any two projections are equivalent in a type III$_1$ factor . For example, $p$ and $q$ are equivalent in type III$_1$ factor $M$.  $1-p$ and $1-q$ are also equivalent. Then there exists a unitary in $M$ such that $p=uqu^*$. I was confused about the conclusion. If the above conclusion holds, then any projection in a type  III$_1$ factor is unitarily equivalent to $1$.

Comment: No. Why would that be?

Comment: But the above conclusion is from Haagerup's paper. It mentions that if $p$ and $q$ are projections in type III factor, then $p$ is equivalent to $q$ and $1-p$ is equivalent to $1-q$. Then there exists a unitary $v$ such that $vqv^*=p$.

Comment: You say that if you take $1$ and $q$ then $1$ is equivalent to $q$ and $0$ is equivalent to $1-q$? Why would that be?

Comment: p,q are non trivial projections?

Comment: Yes. And when $p=1$, is $1-p$ a nontrivial projection?