# a partial isometry generates a finite dimensional factor

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

[image]

In the proof of the Lemma 5.2, I was puzzled by the statement "$v$ generates a finite dimensional factor $F_1$ and...".

Why can $v$ generate a finite dimensional? If $v^i\neq v^j$ for all $i\neq j$, then the von Neumann algebra generated by $v$ is infinite dimensional.

How to check $\varphi_{F_2}=\omega_{\lambda_2}$? where $\omega_{\lambda_2}(e_{11})=\lambda_2, \omega_{\lambda_2}(e_{22})=\frac{ 
\lambda_2}{1+\lambda_2},\omega_{\lambda_2}(e_{12})=\omega_{\lambda_2}(e_{22})=0$ and $e_{11},e_{12},e_{21},e_{22}$ are matrix units of $M_2(\Bbb C)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If $v^i≠v^j$ for all $i≠j$, then the von Neumann algebra generated by $v$ is infinite dimensional.

Not if $v^*v+vv^*=1$. This forces the two projections $v^*v$ and $vv^*$ to be pairwise orthogonal. Then
$$
v^2=v(v^*v)(vv^*)v=0. 
$$
The four elements $v^*v, v, v^*, vv^*$ behave exactly like the matrix units in $M_2(\mathbb C)$. Hence the von Neumann they generate is (a copy of) $M_2(\mathbb C)$.

I don't know the theory the authors are using, so I will just comment on the arithmetic. If you find a partial isometry $v$ with $v\varphi=\lambda_2\varphi v$ and $v^*v+vv^*=1$, then you have
$$
\varphi(vv^*)=\lambda_2\varphi(v^*v),\qquad\qquad \varphi(v^*v)+\varphi(vv^*)=1. 
$$
Solving the $2\times 2$ linear system gives you
$$
\varphi(v^*v)=\frac{\lambda_2}{1+\lambda_2},\qquad\varphi(vv^*)=\frac1{1+\lambda_2}. 
$$
You also have $\varphi(v)=\lambda_2\varphi(v)$, so as long as $\lambda_2\ne1$ you get $\varphi(v)=0$.

Comment: Thanks. I have another question. Is it obvious that $F_1'\cap N \cong eNe$? I cannot construct the concrete  $*$_isomorphism.

Comment: You can get an isomorphism $eNe\to F_1'\cap N$ by doing $$z\longmapsto z+v^*zv$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. According to the above proof, if $\lambda_2=1$, we cannot get $\varphi(v)=0$. Since $S$ is the finite subset of the point spectrum of $\varphi$, by this condition, can we conclude that $\lambda_2\neq 1$.?  Besides, $F_1$ is $*$-isomrphic to $M_2(\Bbb C)$, how to check that $\sigma_t^{\varphi}(F_1)=(F_1), \forall t\in R$?

Comment: I know nothing about the point spectrum of a state (I have never seen such notion) so I cannot comment on that. As for the invariance, if $\lambda_1>0$, for any positive $x\in N$ you have $$\varphi(vv^*x)=\lambda_1\varphi(v^*xv)\geq0.$$ Taking adjoints you get  $\varphi(vv^*x)=\varphi(xvv^*)$. Since this works for $x\geq0$, it works for all $x$ by linearity. So $vv^*\in N_\varphi$, and similarly $v^*v\in N_\varphi$.  But I don't immediately see why the modular group would map $v$ into $F_1$.

Comment: Like I said, I don't know much of the theory so I'm of no help here. What is $M$? You never mentioned anything about it. The equality $\varphi(xy)=\lambda_1\varphi(yx)$ cannot hold in any von Neumann algebra that contains $x$, unless $\lambda_1=1$.

Comment: No, $v^*v\in N_\varphi$ does not tell you that $v\in N_\varphi$. The proof of Ando and Haagerup quotes Takesaki's 1973, but there in Lemma 1.6 he requires $\varphi$ to be periodic.

Comment: But $vv^*$ and $v^*v$ are equivalent projections, By this conclusion, we have $\varphi(vv^*)=\varphi(v^*v)$.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3030312/equivalent-projections-in-finite-factors-are-unitarily-equivalent

Comment: I have no idea how you reach that conclusion. There is no reason to have $\varphi(vv^*)=\varphi(v^*v)$.

Comment: 1. $vv^*$ and $v^*v$ are equivalent projections in $N_{\varphi}$. 2. $\varphi |_{N_{\varphi}}$ is the unique trace on $N_{\varphi}$ Since $N_{\varphi}$ is a type II$_1$ factor. Are the two conclusions correct?

Comment: Yes, but it does not imply that $\varphi(vv^*)=\varphi(v^*v)$. As I already mentioned, no one is saying that $v\in N_\varphi$.